# How can i print the current date, in words, not in numbers?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I want to represent the days, month etc like this:

```
msg1 db 'Today: $'
day db 'one ','two ','three '..
month db 'jan ','feb ','mar ','apr '...
weekday db 'Monday ',...
```

How can i reffer the elements of the strings to create another string, for example: "monday two february"?

Comment: Don't code that in assembly (life is too short); Use the C `strftime` function.

Comment: i really need it in assembly :(

Comment: Either make all your strings the same length, or create a second array (`dw` for 16-bit code) of offsets of your strings. Show us what you've got!

Comment: Keyword: Lookuptable.